# What do you call a dense concentration of stars?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a dense concentration of stars? A dense concentration of stars that looks like a part of the milky way. Many stars stuck together that make it seems that there's a literal blanket of stars.

Comment: I think that this question might be better suited to the Astronomy SE site, since your asking about a particular field's technical jargon.

Answer (score 7):

Star Clusters. They come in two different types. Globular and open clusters. Pleiades is a common one we can see in the night time sky.

Answer (score 0):

When specifically referring to stars that appear to be in the Milky Way, you could also call them a **band** of stars.  Note that stars which appear to be clustered together from our perspective may not actually be anywhere near each other in reality.  2 stars could appear to be close together and of similar magnitude but one of them is actually much further away and brighter.  When you refer to a cluster as in rocket's answer, it tends to imply that they are *actually* somewhat close together, while a band of stars merely implies that they *appear* close together from our perspective.